# Is it necesary to use make_scorer in the scoring argument for pre-defined score object in cross-validation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using different Hyperparameter tunning functions in a classification problem with cross-validation. In particular, I am comparing performance of [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), [RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) and [BayesSearchCV](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/#skopt.BayesSearchCV).

All these functions have the parameter "scoring" where you can specify a string with a [predefined scoring parameter](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter), or a callable to evaluate the predictions on the test set. I understand that sometimes you need to define your own scoring function via this callable using [make_scorer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer). This is fine, no problem.

My question is whether it is preferible converting a given pre-defined score (e.g. average_precision_score, f1_score, ...) into a scorer via `make_scorer` suitable for model selection.

For instance, do this two chunks of code do the same?

1) Using a string in "scoring" argument:

```
    opt = BayesSearchCV(clf,
                    search_spaces,
                    scoring='average_precision',
                    cv=4,
                    n_iter=40,
                    n_jobs=-1)
```

2) Using make_scorer in "scoring" argument:

```
    # define scorer
    avg_prec = make_scorer(average_precision_score, greater_is_better=True, needs_proba=True)

    opt = BayesSearchCV(clf,
                    search_spaces,
                    scoring=avg_prec,
                    cv=4,
                    n_iter=40,
                    n_jobs=-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to do it yourself. Scikit-learn internally does the same thing. So when you provide a string value in `'scoring'` parameter, it is internally matched with a dict of pre-defined scoring methods which contain the `make_scorer(scorer, ...)` as values. See the [source code here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py#L510):

```
SCORERS = dict(explained_variance=explained_variance_scorer,
               ...
               ...
               average_precision=average_precision_scorer,
               ...
               ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. That's what I thought, but I have seen so many people using make_scorer that I doubted about its utility. Also, I have seen defining cv=StratifiedKFold() when in reality this is the default method when setting cv=Integer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroCalleCordón Explicitly using `StratifiedKFold` may be useful for setting the `random_state` which controls the reproducibility of train-test split in folds, which is not possible when using an integer